# jQuery click event on :data selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect click on a pagination anchor through a :data selector with no result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-pageindex="1">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-pageindex="2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-pageindex="3">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a:data(pageindex)").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('anchor clicked!');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any clues about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: :data() selector exists in jQueryUI but the thing is that it's not applicable in your case, check the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/ , you may opt to use Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's answer.

Comment: If you still want to use your own logic (by using the `:data` selector), I think you have to customize your own `:data` selector (don't need jQuery UI), check this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/ , with the `.expr[':']`, you can extend many selectors, not just `:data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`Has attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) at this context,

```
$("a[data-pageindex]").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert('anchor clicked!');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/3RaEn/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no ":data" selector in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid selector. Instead use like this,

```
$("ul > li").each(function(){
     $(this).find("a").data();
     $(this).click(function(){
          console.log($(this).find("a").data().pageindex);
          // do your stuff
     })
});
```

Here's the [Demo Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/embkay06/9GP9P/)